# Getting every third result into a new TR

Tags: php, mysql, html, while-loop

I'm going to get a headache from this one. I have a simple query and a simple table I generate during the query's `while` loop. I want to create a new row after each third result.

```
$customers_num=8; // This is actually mysql_numrows($result) never mind; 

$i=0;
while ($i < $customers_num) {
    if($i % 3 === 0) {
        print '<tr>';
    }

    print '<td style="width: 30%;"></td>';

    if($i % 3 === 0) {
        print '</tr>';
    }

    $i++;
}
```

If the question is not clear, because of my English, I could try to improve the question to bee more precise.

The problem is that I close the `<tr>` right after I open it :S I need to open it, put three TD's into it, and then close it...

Comment: You are missing `$i++` somewhere?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to retype the increment, i have it in the code but that doesn't do the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to increment `$i`. This should do the trick:

```
$customers_num=8; // This is actually mysql_numrows($result) never mind; 

$i=0;
while ($i < $customers_num) {

    if($i % 3 === 0) {
        if ($i > 0) print "</tr>"; //not first row
        if ($i < $customers_num - 1) print '<tr>'; //not last row
    }

    print '<td style="width: 30%;"></td>';

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that I close the TR right after I open it :S I need to open it, put three TD's into it, and then close it..."

Comment: Yeah I added a comment.. Sorry once again.

Comment: It's kind of like the debate over the break statement, I suppose. ([My views](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2657481/1122351).) Your solution is more elegant, but the logic of my solution makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to open tr and print three td in it.

```
$customers_num=8; // This is actually mysql_numrows($result) never mind; 
$data; // an assumed variable containing your data.
for($i = 0; i < $customers_num; $i++){
    echo '<tr>';
    for($j = $i; $j < $i + 3 && $j < $customers_num; $j++){
            echo '<td style="width: 30%;">' . $data[$j] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Please do not use this odd modulus logic that you have suggested. Just have an inner loop for each td required. This allows you to easily change your logic in the future. So that maybe in the future you can chagne it to 5 cells if required, easily.

Comment: Yes but you see, what you did is for each customer, print the same data three times.. I didn't put the query output (lot of print's) to simplify the question.. But I have for example 8 results, and just want to print them so that after each third result, a new html TR is created..

Comment: @AlenBer No i didn't. You haven't suggested any sort of data here at all. If you want to  get the correct data that you're after do echo $data[$j]

Answer (score 1):

i think thats what you want to achieve :

```
$customers_num=8; // This is actually mysql_numrows($result) never mind; 

$i=1;
while ($i < $customers_num) {

    if($i == 1) {
        print '<tr>';
    }

    print '<td style="width: 30%;"></td>';

    if($i == 3 ) {
        print '</tr>';
        $i=0;//next inc. to 1
    }
    $i++;
}

if($i  != 1 )
{
  echo "</tr>";
}
```